# Unable to Optimize with range value for sum of parameters constraint in r

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I am new to **optimization** techniques and and trying to figure out values of **3 parameters**:

`New_budget_fb`,

`New_budget_tv`,

`New_budget_radio`

**Minimize** the value of `CPO`.

But I am not sure about how to add below constraints which is sum of params:

`New_budget_fb + New_budget_tv + New_budget_radio <= 550 &`

`New_budget_fb + New_budget_tv + New_budget_radio >= 350`

Below is the code that I have tried but giving me an error. Have added multiple `print()` to figure out.

```
library(tidyverse)

fn_budget_optim_test <- function(params){
  
  
  # Unknown params used in below equations
  New_budget_fb = params[1]
  New_budget_tv = params[2]
  New_budget_radio = params[3]
  
  print(paste("Parameters 1,2,3:",New_budget_fb,New_budget_tv,New_budget_radio))
  
  contribution_fb = ((70.6 * 1.0 + New_budget_fb)^0.3596438) * 2.015733
  contribution_tv = ((16 * 0.001 + New_budget_tv)^0.8996762) * 1.073207
  contribution_radio = (40.8 * 0.001 + New_budget_radio)^0.001 * -6086.523408
  contribution_intercept = 6081.045489
  
  sales_prediction = sum(contribution_fb,contribution_tv,contribution_radio,contribution_intercept)
  
  print(paste("sales prediction:", sales_prediction))
  
  CPO = (New_budget_fb + New_budget_tv + New_budget_radio) / sales_prediction
  
  print(paste("CPO:",CPO))
  
  
  ## Adding constraint
  if(
    (New_budget_fb + New_budget_tv + New_budget_radio) <= 550 & 
    (New_budget_fb + New_budget_tv + New_budget_radio) >= 350
  ) return(CPO)
  
  else return(NA)
}

optim(par = c(150,150,50),
      fn = fn_budget_optim_test, 
      # lower = c(350,350,350),
      # upper = c(550,550,550),
      method = "L-BFGS-B")
```

**Output & Error:**

```
[1] "Parameters 1,2,3: 150 150 50"
[1] "sales prediction: 82.0849314406196"
[1] "CPO: 4.26387637605802"
[1] "Parameters 1,2,3: 150.001 150 50"
[1] "sales prediction: 82.0849543262375"
[1] "CPO: 4.26388736977254"
[1] "Parameters 1,2,3: 149.999 150 50"
[1] "sales prediction: 82.0849085549353"
[1] "CPO: 4.26386538234082"
Error in optim(par = c(150, 150, 50), fn = fn_budget_optim_test, method = "L-BFGS-B") : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [1]
```

I understood this way of writing constraints from [Optim with constrains video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uB0U9barWM4).

Will appreciate any sort of help here.

**UPDATE:**

Able to attempt this for **equality constraint** using **Rsolnp::solnp** but still not able to do it on **inequlity** as I am not clear about the use of inequlity in this function.

Code attempt below that worked for equality i.e sum of params = 350

```
opt_func <- function(params){
  
  # Unknown params used in below equations
  New_budget_fb = params[1]
  New_budget_tv = params[2]
  New_budget_radio = params[3]
  
  print(paste("Parameters 1,2,3:",New_budget_fb,New_budget_tv,New_budget_radio))
  
  contribution_fb = ((70.6 * 1.0 + New_budget_fb)^0.3596438) * 2.015733
  contribution_tv = ((16 * 0.001 + New_budget_tv)^0.8996762) * 1.073207
  contribution_radio = (40.8 * 0.001 + New_budget_radio)^0.001 * -6086.523408
  contribution_intercept = 6081.045489
  
  sales_prediction = sum(contribution_fb,contribution_tv,contribution_radio,contribution_intercept)
  
  print(paste("sales prediction:", sales_prediction))
  
  CPO = (New_budget_fb + New_budget_tv + New_budget_radio) / sales_prediction
  
  print(paste("CPO:",CPO))
  return(CPO)  
}

  ## Adding constraint
equality_func <- function(params){
  New_budget_fb = params[1]
  New_budget_tv = params[2]
  New_budget_radio = params[3]
  
  New_budget_fb + New_budget_tv + New_budget_radio
}

Rsolnp::solnp(c(5,5,5),
      opt_func, #function to optimise
      eqfun=equality_func, #equality constrain function 
      eqB=350,   #the equality constraint value
      LB=c(0,0,0) #lower bound for parameters i.e. greater than zero      
)
```

Comment: It seems that you can make `sale_prediction` extremely small and negative. For example `params = c(254.67552, 29.38246, 228.07362)`. Because `sale_prediction`  is denominator your minimum is extremely negative number.

Comment: Yes & this is where I would like another constraint to add: `CPO >=0` and I am not sure how to add this constraint as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to add the different constraints in the objective function and do the minimization :

```
library(DEoptim)

fn_budget_optim_test <- function(params)
{
  New_budget_fb <- params[1]
  New_budget_tv <- params[2]
  New_budget_radio <- params[3]

  contribution_fb <- ((70.6 * 1.0 + New_budget_fb) ^ 0.3596438) * 2.015733
  contribution_tv <- ((16 * 0.001 + New_budget_tv) ^ 0.8996762) * 1.073207
  contribution_radio <- (40.8 * 0.001 + New_budget_radio) ^ 0.001 * -6086.523408
  contribution_intercept <- 6081.045489
  
  sales_prediction <- sum(contribution_fb, contribution_tv, contribution_radio, contribution_intercept)
  CPO <- (New_budget_fb + New_budget_tv + New_budget_radio) / sales_prediction
  
  if(is.nan(CPO))
  {
    return(10 ^ 30)
    
  }else
  {
    if((New_budget_fb + New_budget_tv + New_budget_radio) <= 550 & 
       (New_budget_fb + New_budget_tv + New_budget_radio) >= 350 &
       (CPO >= 0))
    {
      return(CPO)
      
    }else
    {
      return(10 ^ 30)
    } 
  }
}

obj_DEoptim <- DEoptim(fn = fn_budget_optim_test, lower = rep(0, 3), upper = rep(550, 3),
                       control = list(itermax = 1000))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... I haven't tried this code but accepting it for the moment.

Comment: Hi, you do not have to accept the answer before trying the code ;) There is no need to rush